# Excel VBA: Read, update, and set a series' XVALUES

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to read, then update, and then set a series XVALUE properties

step 1) x = cht.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues
For example x = "=Dashboard!$S$137:$X$137", note the $X

Step 2) Modify X
For example x = "=Dashboard!$S$137:$W$137", note the $W

Step 3) cht.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = x

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code assumes that the workbook containing the chart is the active workbook.  If this is not the case, make sure that it is in fact the active workbook.

```
    Dim sr As Series
    Set sr = cht.FullSeriesCollection(1)
        
    Dim seriesFormula As String
    seriesFormula = sr.Formula
    
    Dim oldXValuesFormula As String
    oldXValuesFormula = Split(seriesFormula, ",")(1)
    
    With Range(oldXValuesFormula)
        Dim newXValuesFormula As String
        newXValuesFormula = .Resize(, .Columns.Count - 1).Address(external:=True)
    End With
    
    sr.XValues = Range(newXValuesFormula)
```

Comment: That gave me everything I need to solve my puzzle. Thanks so much @domenic!!!